# Coordinates of Polygon layer

Tags: openlayers-2, mapserver

i am using Mapserver map file and  Openlayers to display a polygon layer on the Google map.
layer is displaying but that layer is not on the center.
i have used `map.setcenter`, but i do not know the lat lon values of the polygon layer
how do Io get these polygon values?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a vectorlayer you can use the getDataExtent()-Method.
Otherwise you can also just set the extent manually, grab the centerpoint for this extent and use this centerpoint to center the map:

Just move the map to the extent you like and get the coordinates in your console:

```
map.events.register("moveend", map, function () {
    var centerpoint = map.getCenter().toShortString();
    console.log(centerpoint);
});
```

Of course you can also just use map.getCenter().toShortString() in your console without registering the moveend-event.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/osyvowg0/